# Does the map $y_{n+1} = (r y_n) \bmod 1$ exhibit periodic doubling upon varying the parameter $r$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

My initial thought is that it does from my understanding on reading the material regarding flip bifurcations but the $\bmod 1$ is throwing me off here so I can’t be sure. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Certainly not in the way that $x\mapsto rx(1-x)$ does. I guess some smoothness was necessary. Really, when is your mapping periodic?

Comment: You are correct this is nothing like the logistic map which experiences period doubling. 
I have considered the map in my question in terms of r<1, r=1 and r>1 and in none of the cases does it appear to show any periodic behaviour.

Comment: Well, it is periodic for _some carefully chosen_ initial values, but that's about it. No attractors, that's for sure.